# Does the "Power Profiles" PDF for M&M 3e contain all individual profiles?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Green Ronin offers a lot of different "power profile" PDFs for 3e, each focusing on one power type. However, there's also a book called Power Profiles, stated to contain over thirty power types. The description for Power Profiles lists some types that appear to be available individually as well.

Is Power Profiles a bundle of all individually available power profiles? Are there any that are not included? Conversely, does Power Profiles contain any profiles which are not available individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bundle of all of the individual items. I just did a spot check from the book and the website. They are all accounted for and there are none extra. The chief advantage to the collected edition is price — it's much cheaper to buy them in bulk — and in the extra sidebars discussing how to handle tricky powers.

Incidentally, it's not a bad question because the Threat Reports did omit one or two entries, I think because they planned on putting those ones into the upcoming Freedom City book.